# How to exit from infinite loop in parent terminal?

Tags: bash, infinite-loop

To test `trap` command I created the following loop in terminal:

```
while true ; do echo BEGIN ; bash -e ; echo "exit code = $?" ; echo END ; done
```

How to exit this loop and turn back to the parent shell?

In case of using remote shell (`ssh`) instead of `bash` there is a delay during connection establishing process when I can press <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>. But in the above case I can't be fast enough to catch time window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case exiting the child shell causes another child shell to appear immediately. To break the loop execute this from within the child shell:

```
kill -s SIGINT $PPID
```

Then exit the child shell (`exit` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>). `$PPID` ensures the signal gets to the parent shell (without playing with `ps` and guessing).

Comment: `SIGINT` is Ctrl+C?

Comment: @Orient. Yes. See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/362559/108618).